# Rails rich text editor for different languages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rich-text-editor

I am building a Rails 4 app, where I want users to be able to read/write/upload/download files with different kind of files with color highlighting depending on the programming language of the file. Currently I've found a few gems which allow you to **read** a file and display with color highlighting, just like sublime or any other rich text editor.

I haven't found any text-editor which allows you to choose a language, and based on that highlight the words depending on the language chosen.

I'm looking for something like the editor   [gistbox](http://www.gistboxapp.com/) has, but haven't found anything yet.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to get.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sent a mail to the creator of gisthub, with the following information:

To read a file, and have a nice view in any language use the following: [highlightJS](http://highlightjs.org/)

To have a nice editor which recognizes different kind of languages use [ace](http://ace.c9.io/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [gem Github is using](https://github.com/github/linguist)? That might be exactly what you want.

If not, it might be possible to use a gem like [highlight](https://github.com/simplabs/highlight) and use a refresh via jquery to generate a div with the highlighted text, maybe even within the textarea -which could be a little tricky, but should be possible-